# Обработка xml документа в c#. Перебор с условием

Tags: c#, xml, vkontakte-api

Есть xml документ вида:

```
<response list="true">
<photo>
          <pid>380712118</pid> 
          <aid>-7</aid> 
          <src>...</src> 
          <src_big>...</src_big> 
          <src_small>...</src_small> 
          <width>319</width> 
          <height>604</height> 
          <text /> 
          <created>1441633562</created> 
          <post_id>30</post_id> 
</photo>
    ........
<photo>
          <pid>380712118</pid> 
          <aid>-7</aid> 
          <src>...</src> 
          <src_big>...</src_big> 
          <src_small>...</src_small> 
          <width>319</width> 
          <height>604</height> 
          <text /> 
          <created>1441633562</created> 
          <post_id>30</post_id> 
</photo>
```

Подскажите, как вытащить из него все значения "src" блока "photo" где поле "created" соответствует какому либо условию.
Просто пройтись по списку и вывести все элементы я могу конструкцией типа

```
foreach (XmlElement element in xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("photo"))
                {
                    foreach (XmlElement e in element.GetElementsByTagName("src")) /
                    {
                       ...
                    }
                }
```

далее у меня возникают проблемы как составить правильное условие. Может я вообще изначально не правильно пытаюсь пройтись по списку и в цикл foreach при работе с XmlDocument такое условие не запихнешь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам поможет Linq2Xml. Попробуйте следующий код:

```
XElement xe = XElement.Load(filename);

var srcs =
    xe.Elements("photo")
    .Where(element => element.Element("created").Value == "1441633562")
    .Select(element => element.Element("src").Value);
    .ToList();
srcs.ForEach(element => Console.WriteLine(element));
```

Для того чтобы это работало нужны пространства имён `System.Linq` и `System.Xml.Linq`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте, например, так:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(s);
foreach (var photo in doc.Descendants("photo")
                         .Where(e => (int)e.Element("created") >= 1441633562))
    Console.WriteLine((int)photo.Element("pid"));
```

(И [переходите с `XmlDOcument` на более современный `XDocument`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1542101/276994).)